Software for programming classes (for teacher)
I'm looking for some software to support teacher of programming.
My ideas/requirements:

I would like to be sure, everyone has the same IDE and environment (e.g. same python version and libraries) on lesson start (so maybe some way to ensure same IDE and environment on each workstation, or some browser based IDE?)
I would like to remotely distribute some code/lessons  for students, so that everyone can start with the same code/or db/ or test data
I would like to be able to see each student IDE/screen and be able to show it to everyone, and be able to edit there (so take over control).

Is it possible?

Please provide more information on the environment you're working with - Windows, Mac, other; what resources do you have available (for example, would it be viable to virtualize the environment); do you require FOSS or is commercial software acceptable; must it be a single package, or is a different package for each aspect of the problem acceptable; etc.
